# Decrypt file using GnuPG

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I am trying to decrypt a set of files with GnuPG, for which I already have the username and password. However, I cannot seem to be able to do so, even though I have generated a new key with the given credentials. When trying to run

```
gpg --output result.sc --decrypt myFile.sc.xz.gpg
```

I get:

```
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID 3662FD5E
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

I am wondering, which are the steps in decrypting with GnuPG? I followed the instructions here http://linoxide.com/security/gpg-comand-linux-how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-file/, but still did not get it to work. I have no other key given except for these credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the private key with `3662FD5E`.

> I have no other key given except for these credentials.

Without this key, you cannot decrypt the file. The password you have might protect the private key, but without the private key, there's definitely no way to decrypt the file (unless in future, a way is found to crack the encryption, but as of now, pretty much all relevant and actually used algorithms in OpenPGP are believed to be secure).

> even though I have generated a new key with the given credentials

Keys are generated from random numbers, you cannot generate the same key again, also when using the same user ID and password.